# java multidimensional arrays row sum and column sum

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int rows, cols, j, i;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter no of rows and columns respectively");
    rows = sc.nextInt();
    cols = sc.nextInt();
    int[][] matrix = new int[rows+1][cols+1];
    System.out.println("enter elements");
    for(i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            matrix[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("after sum");
    int grandtotal = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        int rowsum = 0;
        int colsum = 0;
        for(j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            rowsum += matrix[i][j];
            colsum += matrix[j][i];
        }
        matrix[i][j] = rowsum;
        grandtotal += rowsum;
        matrix[j][i] = colsum;
    }
    j = cols;
    matrix[i][j] = grandtotal;
```

The above code is working fine, but my question is: using this logic, how can I find the `grandtotal` for a matrix if the number of rows and columns are not the same? And tell me if there are any flaws with my current code.

Comment: Where's the problem in iterating over all cells and summing them? If the number of columns/rows is different for each row/column then use `matrix[i].length` for the inner loop. Or is the problem finding the last cell in the last row? If so try `row[] = matrix[matrix.length-1];row[row.length-1]=grandtotal;`.

Comment: @Pratik Thacker As a computer engineer you should always think of solutions that reuse existing solutions.Just like in this case.

Comment: @Pratik Thacker Not only the code has become smaller but also can deal with any input related to number of rows and columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no flaw in your code.Now coming to the point when the number of rows and columns are different.

The statement

```
matrix[j][i] = colsum;
```

now would give incorrect result because now number of rows and number of columns are different.

This can be solved very easily by just changing the statement

```
colsum += matrix[j][i];
```

to:

```
matrix[rows][j] += matrix[i][j];
```

and now you do not need the statement

```
matrix[j][i] = colsum;
```

So with these simple modifications, the code for different number of columns and rows would be:

```
for( i = 0;i < rows;i++)
{
    int rowsum=0;
    for( j = 0;j < cols;j++)
    {
    rowsum += matrix[i][j];
    matrix[rows][j] += matrix[i][j];
    }
    matrix[i][j] = rowsum;
    grandtotal += rowsum;        
}
```

Keep Rest of the code same.

Comment: some spaces and code formatting would make your code readable.